# How to reverse generated integer order in python

Tags: python-3.5

This code produces one number after the other as it converts decimal to binary.

```
dec = int(input("Please enter number to convert to decimal: "))   
    while dec>0:
        quoteint = dec/2
        rem = dec%2
        print (int(rem), end = " ")
        dec = int(dec/2)
```

The output is the following.

```
1 0 0 1 0
```

Is there a way to reverse the output order?

Eg. `0 1 0 0 1`

It may work if the individual numbers generated are joined to a string and the string is reversed, but I don't know how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code will work.

```
result = []
dec = int(input("Please enter number to convert to decimal: "))   
while dec>0:
    quoteint = dec/2
    rem = dec%2
    result.append(rem)
    dec = int(dec/2)
result = result[::-1]
print(' '.join(str(r) for r in result))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried your suggestion and it works fine. Thanks a lot.